# Why does my extended THREE.MeshStandardMaterial fail to display shadow when map is used?

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl

I was in need of a Three.js material that lets me crossfade one texture into another, while receiving shadows from a spotlight source.

```
const plane = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.PlaneGeometry(200, 200, 1, 1),
    new TextureFadeMaterial({
        t: 0.5,
        map: texture1,
        mapDest: texture2,
    })
);
plane.receiveShadow = true;
```

So i went ahead and 'extended' THREE.MeshStandardMaterial, and added the uniforms `mapDest` (the second texture) and `t` (number 0..1). I modified the `map_fragment` chunk to mix `map` and `mapDest` together depending on the value of t.

The problem was that as soon as i had it render a texture, the shadow disappeared. In fact, as soon as i put `vec4 texelColor = texture2D( map, vUv );` and nothing else in place of the `map_fragment` chunk (appears before the code responsible for shadows), the shadow disappeared (super weird because `texelColor` is never used in this test case).

I wonder why that is.

I got it to work by moving the modified `map_fragment` chunk to the end of the fragment shader (after the light/shadow code is executed).

Here's the final TextureFadeMaterial code:

https://gist.github.com/claus/854963f2cd42ab21acf9cdba4fef49f3
(see line 156ff and 187ff)

And in case you're interested, here's the unwrapped MeshStandardMaterial fragment shader code:

https://gist.github.com/claus/d348483b9fcbd2110fda1c44fe31cf80